# retrieve values from keys with the same name android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get the string in the two key called title without knowing the parent key with the date.
Consider that other key with the name title will be added programmatically.

[image]

Comment: Sounds feasible. Did you try anything yet? If not, I'd recommend starting with the [Firebase documentation for Android developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/), and the corresponding [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/). They will give you a solid starting point. If you did try something already, update your question to show the [minimal complete code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So basically you want to get all the titles within those date objects, right?

Comment: exactly maybe in an array string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Filippo Profeta").orderByChild("title");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(title);
            Log.d("TAG", title);
        }

        //Do what you need to do with your list
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logacat will be, all the titles of your dates. If you need to convert the `title` string or the list in any other formats, feel free to do it.